# Android XML Parsing omitting "&amp;"

Tags: xml, android, parsing, sax

The problem again is that though i have succesfully implemented a SAX parser in my code... It is behaving wierdly. It jus skips the enteries after the & and goes to the next entry. Just wanted to know whether this is the typical working of SAX parser or m i implementing it wrongly???

I have implemented org.xml.sax.ContentHandler and have provided the following coding inside...

`

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
         {
             if(lastName.equals("id"))
             {
                 String id = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
                 CustomList.idvector.add(id);
             }
             else if(lastName.equals("subcategory"))
             {
                String subcategory = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
                 CustomList.subcategoryvector.add(subcategory);
             }
             else if(lastName.equals("photo"))
             {
                 String photo = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
                 CustomList.photovector.add(photo);
             }
             else if(lastName.equals("name"))
             {
                 String name = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
                 CustomList.namevector.add(name);
             }
         }
```

`

There are elements with tags ,,,... and m taking those info into a vector... is this correct???

Now again problem is that i cant parse special character like "$" and such... is there any way we can catch these characters??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure exactly what you're seeing, if this doesn't help deal with your problem maybe you could provide some sample input and output.

`&amp;` is an XML entity reference and means `&`.

By default, SAX will do the conversion for you, so if your source XML says `hello&amp;goodbye` you should see `hello&goodbye`.

It may also be that SAX is breaking up the calls to the `characters()` method because of the entity reference. You may need to concatenate multiple calls to `characters()` together whilst still inside the same tag.

Comment: But 1 more doubt... it is foolish of me asking it but does space create any problems??

Comment: By the way Brabster can u provide some coding for the same... i mean i kind of figured out that the problem is actually in concatenation... can u plz give an example of String concatenation in this case... how to check whether the next char is &amp???

Comment: Apologies, wasn't around my computer. Glad you sorted your problem out.

Comment: On android characters() is indeed called multiple times while inside same tag, so for input "bob &amp; jay" there will be three separate calls.

Answer (score 1):

This worked 4 me guys... Thanx Brabster...

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
             {
                 if(lastName.equals("id") && (lastName != lastElementTraversed))
                 {
                     String s = new String(ch, start, length);
                     if (appendedid == null) 
                     {
                         appendedid = new StringBuffer(s);
                     } else {
                          appendedid.append(s);
                     }

                 }
            else if(lastName.equals("subcategory")&& (lastName !=lastElementTraversed))
                 {
                     String s = new String(ch, start, length);
                     if (appendedsub == null) {
                         appendedsub = new StringBuffer(s);
                      } else {
                          appendedsub.append(s);
                      }
                     //lastElementTraversed = lastName;
                 }
            else if(lastName.equals("photo")&& (lastName != lastElementTraversed))
                 {
                     String s = new String(ch, start, length);
                      if (appendedphoto == null) {
                          appendedphoto = new StringBuffer(s);
                      } else {
                          appendedphoto.append(s);
                      }
                      //lastElementTraversed = lastName;
                 }
            else if(lastName.equals("name") && (lastName != lastElementTraversed))
                 {
                     String s = new String(ch, start, length);
                      if (appendedname == null) {
                          appendedname = new StringBuffer(s);
                      } else {
                          appendedname.append(s);
                      } 
                      //lastElementTraversed = lastName;
                 }
             }
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
            {
                lastName = localName;
                appendedid=null;
                appendedsub=null;
                appendedphoto=null;
                appendedname=null;

            }

             public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
             {
                 lastElementTraversed = localName;
                 if(localName.equals("category"))
                    {
                        appendedid=null;
                        appendedsub=null;
                        appendedphoto=null;
                        appendedname=null;

                    }

                     if(appendedid!=null)
                     CustomList.idvector.add(appendedid.toString());
                     if(appendedsub!=null)
                     CustomList.subcategoryvector.add(appendedsub.toString());
                     if(appendedphoto!=null)
                     CustomList.photovector.add(appendedphoto.toString());
                     if(appendedname!=null)
                     CustomList.namevector.add(appendedname.toString());

             }
        }
```

Comment: Well actually m checking a lot of things coz the XML file my client has is really messy... forget the things u don understand... i guess u'll understand most of it... :)

Comment: hi guys the problem again is that i cant catch the special characters like "$" and bullets n all... is there a way out in SAX parsing or do we need to shift to some other parsing method... does JSON fix this???