# SAX Parser does not parse specal characters "&"

Tags: android, xml-parsing, special-characters, saxparser

I'm using SAX Parser to parse an xml like this one:

```
<items>
 <item>
   <id>1000</id>
   <title>Rock Music</title>
 </item>

 <item>
   <id>1011</id>
   <title>R&B Music</title>
 </item>
......................
```

When I parse I can get just:

```
1000 Rock Music
1011
```

but not text that contains special character and nothing after...it stops there. I'm all right with blank spaces, the problem is just with special char.
    I have tried :

```
 InputSource is = new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream());
 is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); //also "UTF-8" and other encoding but didn't work.
```

How can I extract and display text that contains "&" supposing that I have no access editing the xml?, (I heard that if you write `&amp;` when you write the xml it works fine !?)

Comment: this is not valid xml ... you **have to use** `&amp;` instead `&`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973483/android-xml-parsing-omitting-amp

Comment: what I have post, is how I see it in browser, I have no acces to edit it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap the input in something like a [`FilterInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and [HTML-encode](http://goo.gl/8KUQV) the text yourself before SAX sees it.

But, really, you should speak to whoever is sending this data, and get them to fix the broken XML.

Comment: I will speak to him, to see if the problem is there and comeback with what I get. Thanks!